# List Index out of Range Python Function

Tags: python

I keep getting List Index out of Range and also my string length check for the barcode isn't working. I was told there was no value inside the array, but I don't know how to check if there is a value and how to fix it if there isn't. I'm new to using classes in python.

```
 class ZipCode():
        def __init__(self,number):
                if (encode == "Yes" or encode == "yes"):
                        self.number = 1
                else:
                        self.number = ""
        def EncodeNumber(self):
                self.number = str(self.number)
                a = []
                a += list(self.number)
                zipcode1 = int(a[0])
                zipcode2 = int(a[1])
                zipcode3 = int(a[2])
                zipcode4 = int(a[3])
                zipcode5 = int(a[4])
                barcode1 += `(zipcode1 / 7)`
                barcode1 += `(zipcode1 / 4)`
                barcode1 += `(zipcode1 / 2)`
                barcode1 += `(zipcode1 / 1)`
                if (barcode1.count("1") >= 2):
                        barcode1 += "0"
                else:
                        barcode1 += "1"
                barcode2 += `(zipcode2 / 7)`
                barcode2 += `(zipcode2 / 4)`
                barcode2 += `(zipcode2 / 2)`
                barcode2 += `(zipcode2 / 1)`
                if (barcode2.count("1") >= 2):
                        barcode2 += "0"
                else:
                        barcode2 += "1"
                barcode3 += `(zipcode3 / 7)`
                barcode3 += `(zipcode3 / 4)`
                barcode3 += `(zipcode3 / 2)`
                barcode3 += `(zipcode3 / 1)`
                if (barcode3.count("1") >= 2):
                        barcode3 += "0"
                else:
                        barcode3 += "1"
                barcode4 += `(zipcode4 / 7)`
                barcode4 += `(zipcode4 / 4)`
                barcode4 += `(zipcode4 / 2)`
                barcode4 += `(zipcode4 / 1)`
                if (barcode4.count("1") >= 2):
                        barcode4 += "0"
                else:
                        barcode4 += "1"
                barcode5 += `(zipcode5 / 7)`
                barcode5 += `(zipcode5 / 4)`
                barcode5 += `(zipcode5 / 2)`
                barcode5 += `(zipcode5 / 1)`
                if (barcode1.count("1") >= 2):
                        barcode5 += "0"
                else:
                        barcode5 += "1"
                self.number = "1" + barcode1 + barcode2 + barcode3 + barcode4 + barcode5 + "1"
        def DecodeNumber(self):
                b = []
                b += list(self.number)
                barcode1 = int(b[0])
                barcode2 = int(b[1])
                barcode3 = int(b[2])
                barcode4 = int(b[3])
                barcode5 = int(b[4])
                self.number = ((barcode1 * 7) + (barcode2 * 4) + (barcode3 * 2) + (barcode4 * 1) + (barcode5 * 0 ))

        def returnZipCode(self):
                return self.number
        def returnBarCode(self):
                return self.number
if __name__ == "__main__":
        encode = "Yes"
        encode = raw_input("If you would like to encode a zip code type Yes, else type No:")
        if (encode == "yes" or encode == "Yes"):
                x = raw_input("Enter the Zipcode you would like to be encoded!:")
                ZipC = ZipCode(x)
                ZipC.EncodeNumber()
                ZipC.returnBarCode()
                print "Holy Jeebus It worked!"
        else:
                x = raw_input("Enter a 5 digit binary number you would like to be decoded based on POSTNET standards!:")
                while (len(x) != 5):
                        print "Invalid Barcode!"
                        x = raw_input("Enter a 5 digit binary number you would like to be decoded based on POSTNET standards!:")         
                ZipC = ZipCode(x)
                ZipC.DecodeNumber()
                ZipC.returnZipCode()
                print "Holy Jeebus It worked!"
```

Comment: To format code here - Copy/Paste it to the question, select it all, press `ctrl` + `k`. This will automatically add 4 spaces to everything.

Comment: It looks like you are only adding 1 string to the array (`a += zipcode`), but then you try to get 5 strings out with `a[0]` `a[1]` etc... If there is only 1 item then only `a[0]` exists.

Comment: It looks like you will have a similar problem later on in the code with `b += barcode` and then `b[0]` `b[1]` etc...

Comment: I was trying to split each character of the string up into an array

Comment: If it's possible for you to use a list you can do `list(zipcode)` which will split it up for you.

Comment: I tried doing that and I got the same error

Comment: When I run the code you posted I get `invalid syntax error`. Is the code you posted _exactly_ the same as the code you are running? If so what version of python are you using?

Comment: It is and I'm usin 2.7

Comment: Ahh, I'm running 3.3.2 atm and might not be able to test or reproduce anything I work out for you. I will try to get back to you on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65863/discussion-between-lramos15-and-takendarkk).

Comment: psst, in Python 2.7 you can convert a number to binary with `bin(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try answering your question - but you haven't asked a question. But your code has several things wrong.

List Index out of range comes from this bit:

```
zipcode = 1                  
ZipCode(x).EncodeNumber()    
zipcode = str(zipcode)
a = []                       # inside EncodeNumber
a += zipcode                 # a is now a list with one item, a string 
                             # representation of a number in it e.g. ["34567"]
zipcode1 = int(a[0])         # a[0] is the string "4567"
zipcode2 = int(a[1])         # a[1] is an error
```

Your "length check for barcode" is:

```
while (len(x) > 5):
    print "Invalid Barcode!"
    x = raw_input("Enter a 5 digit binary number you would like to be decoded based on POSTNET standards!:")
```

You don't explain what "it isn't working" means, but you've written it to check for only barcodes "greater than length 5" It says nothing about forbidding barcodes of length 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, so it will count those as valid, and it does nothing about ensuring they are binary numbers (e.g. contains only 0 and 1).

> I'm new to using classes in python.

Indeed. You aren't too far away from forcing a 5 character number and making this code basically 'work'. But you're quite a long way away from happy code that makes sense to the reader.

I'm not sure what to put here; you need a good tutorial and some push to use the interactive interpreter (Python.exe, /usr/bin/Python, IDLE, PythonWin, or whatever) to play with code in 'realtime' without writing huge scripts first.

Just for example:

```
barcode = ""
zipcode = 1
encode = "Yes"
encode = raw_input("If you would like to encode a zip code type Yes, else type No:")

class ZipCode():
        def __init__(self,number):
                if (encode == "Yes" or encode == "yes"):
                        self.number = 1
                        self.number = zipcode
                else:
                        self.number = ""
                        self.number = barcode
```

You passed `number` into `__init__` and then did nothing with it. You reached for `zipcode` which is defined before the class, it's outside, in a different *scope*. You *can* read it, it works, but it's bad design - classes and objects are there to wrap code up in neat packaging. Having bits reach out through the packaging and grab random values is asking for problems.

And here in the next method is the kind of problem:

```
        def EncodeNumber(self):
                zipcode = str(zipcode)
                ..
                barcode = "1" + barcode1 + barcode2 + barcode3 + barcode4 + barcode5 + "1"
```

What this does is reach for the *global* zipcode out there above the class definition, then create a `zipcode` variable within the method of the same name, and give it the same value. Then later, you assign to barcode, which is a *local* variable within the method, it just happens to have the same name as the outside 'barcode'. You think you have kept this barcode because it has the same name, but you haven't, that result is lost when the method finishes running.

It's valid code, but it's misleading you into thinking that it works one way, when it doesn't. And that's one reason your code isn't working.

Using `self.whatever` everywhere inside the class methods is a good plan. EncodeNumber should be working with the `self.number` you put there inside `__init__`.

```
        def returnZipCode(self):
                return zipcode
        def returnBarCode(self):
                return barcode
```

These should be returning `self.zipcode` or similar.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        if (encode == "yes" or encode == "Yes"):
                x = raw_input("Enter the Zipcode you would like to be encoded!:")
                ZipCode(x).EncodeNumber()
                returnBarCode()
```

Here, ZipCode(x) returns an object, which you don't save in a variable. Your call to returnBarCode() isn't calling anything. It needs to be more like:

```
zipC = ZipCode(x)
zipC.EncodeNumber()
zipC.returnBarCode()
```

Comment: When it comes to the arrays I am trying to split the string into individual characters.

Comment: Yes, you said. And someone commented with the command that will split a string into characters and you said "i tried that and got the same error". My answer is an explanation of why it didn't work. Your code is always doing `list(str(1))` and never anything else no matter what you type in, because it's taking the number from the first `zipcode=1` line at the top of the program.

Comment: Do you mind viewing my current code. I still get the index error, but I used self.number

Comment: It's an improvement, but in `__init__` you set `self.number = 1`, no matter what you typed in. You need to take the number into __init__ and then store that in self with `self.number=number`. Then when EncodeNumber reads `self.number` it gets the same value you put into init earlier. (The methods inside the class, and the data in *self*, is all carried around together, and all the methods can share it).

Comment: Now it gets all the way to the end but never returns a value.

Comment: Is that because you ask for `ZipC.returnZipCode()` to get a result, but you don't save it or print it?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to accomplish https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-THpCu8u8vX0/VHkKRfNyvRI/AAAAAAAACBk/YD1cpi57qbc/w590-h797-no/IMG_20141128_185006.jpg

Comment: `print ZipC.returnZipCode()`.

Comment: It prints a value just my logic is wrong. the number doesn't consist of 1's and 0's and doesn't follow the rules.